# attempting to convert varchar to date in Impala

Tags: impala

Any suggestions on converting varchar (12/01/2020) to a date in Impala? Have tried using cast, converting to timestamp but continues to error or have null values. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pls use `select to_timestamp('12/01/2020', 'MM/dd/yyyy');`

Comment: thank you for response. any suggestions on removing the timestamp and keeping the date intact with using extract?        9/28/2017 12:00:00 AM

Comment: You can use `select trunc(to_timestamp('12/01/2020', 'MM/dd/yyyy'),'dd') as dt`. You can use `to_date()` as well if you want a string output like '2020-12-01'. If trunc doesnt work, i will give you correct format tomorrow morning.